# SQL/Oracle: when indexes on multiple columns can be used

Tags: oracle, indexing

If I create an index on columns (A, B, C), in that order, my understanding is that the database will be able to use it even if I search only on (A), or (A and B), or (A and B and C), but not if I search only on (B), or (C), or (B and C). Is this correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are actually three index-based access methods that Oracle can use when a predicate is placed on a non-leading column of an index.

i) Index skip-scan: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/optimops.htm#PFGRF10105

ii) Fast full index scan: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/optimops.htm#i52044

iii) Index full scan: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/optimops.htm#i82107

I've most often seen the fast full index scan "in the wild", but all are possible.

Comment: Does Oracle optimize for the (A, C) case?

Comment: @kd304 I'm not sure if anything other than a fast full index scan is available as an optimisation for that, although a range scan on A might be available. It would certainly be version dependent. There is of course the matter of whether certain scan types can be effectively "pushed" with the use of optimiser hints, rather than leaving the optimiser to do its own thing.

Answer (score 9):

That is not correct. Always best to come up with a test case that represents your data and see for yourself. If you want to really understand the Oracle SQL Optimizer google Jonathan Lewis, read his books, read his blog, check out his website, the guy is amazing, and he always generates test cases.

```
create table mytab nologging as (
select mod(rownum, 3) x, rownum  y, mod(rownum, 3) z from all_objects, (select 'x' from user_tables where rownum < 4)
);

create index i on mytab (x, y, z);

exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname=>'DBADMIN',tabname=>'MYTAB', cascade=>true);

set autot trace exp

select * from mytab where y=5000;

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
   0      SELECT STATEMENT Optimizer=CHOOSE (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=10)
   1    0   INDEX (SKIP SCAN) OF 'I' (INDEX) (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=10)
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning Jonathan Lewis and for the example as well.

Answer (score 5):

**Up to version Oracle 8** an index will never be used unless the first column is included in the SQL.

In Oracle 9i the **Skip Scan Index Access** feature was introduced, which lets the Oracle CBO attempt to use indexes even when the prefix column is not available.

Good overview of how skip scan works here: http://www.quest-pipelines.com/newsletter-v5/1004_C.htm