# What kind of index do I need when there is > operator?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Here is my table:

```
// mytable
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | user_id |  unix_time  |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 1  | 324435  | 1481199265  |
| 2  | 745645  | 1481194241  |
| 3  | 547346  | 1481291987  |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

And this is my current composite index:

```
mytable(user_id, unix_time)
```

And this is one of my queries:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE unix_time < unix_timestamp(subdate(now(), interval '1' YEAR))
```

---

I've read somewhere:

> When there is `>` or `<` or `BETWEEN` or `>=` or `<=` operators, then that column should be the last one in the composite index.

So as you see, there is both `<` operator and `unix_time` is the last one in my current index *(I've created index above because of another query)* .. Now I want to know, Either:

- Do I need to create one more index like `mytable(unix_time)` to benefit query about

Or

- Quoted sentence is right and no need to any index else for query above

?

Comment: Well it looks like unix_time is the last field mentioned in your composite index, so I dont understand the question. Are you getting errors?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no no, there isn't any error, just I want to know, do I need to make another index or current index it enough ?

Comment: I am pretty sure you answered your own question. If it works its right

Comment: @Bert Yes I do. As I've mentioned in the question, I use this composite index `mytable(user_id, unix_time)`

Comment: I think the index does not work, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795031/how-do-composite-indexes-work

Comment: @RiggsFolly The problem is when I run my query by writing `EXPLAIN` in the beginning of it, `key` column is NULL .. so it doesn't use any index

Comment: The answers are fine.  Going beyond this Q&A, find [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) more discussion of how to make the 'best' index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to create one more index like mytable(unix_time) to benefit query

Yes.  It's not the < vs > or = that is the issue.  It's which columns are in the index, and in which order.

If you were doing

```
DELETE FROM mytable 
WHERE unix_time < unix_timestamp(subdate(now(), interval '1' YEAR))
    AND user_id=123456
```

then the index on user_id+unix_time would get used.  Also, if your existing index were on unix_time+user_id, instead of user_id+unix_time, then the database could use it.

And yes, this is accurate:

> When there is > or < or BETWEEN or >= or <= operators, then that column should be the last one in the composite index.

but in this case, because you were not also selecting on user_id, it didn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Only plan of query shows how to run a query. But you offered bad index for that query because unix_time is second field. The good indexes for that query are

```
mytable(unix_time, user_id)
```

or

```
mytable(unix_time)
```

but only the query plan shows whether or not it will be used.