# Why does EF Core 2.1 only add 1 index for 2 FKs?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.1

I use SQL Server 2017 (v14.0.2027.2) and EF Core 2.1.

After I added migration on this code:

```
public class TblTrack
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class TblProduct
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class TblProductItem
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public long ProductId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public long TrackId { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public TblProduct Product { get; set; }
    public TblTrack Track { get; set; }
}
```

Ef Core creates only TrackId index

```
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
name: "IX_tbl_ProductItems_TrackId",
table: "tbl_ProductItems",
column: "TrackId");
```

Why was an index created for `TrackId` but not for `ProductId`?

Comment: Side note: FK/PK relationships work best if both key columns involved are the **same** datatype - you have `long` for the PK in the two tables, but `int` for FK in the referencing table - this should really be the same (either both `int`, or both `long`)

Comment: Also: the spelling on these key fields: you have `ID` and `TrackID` for the key that gets generated (where `ID` is all uppercase), and you have  `Id` and `ProductID` where again you're not being consistent - once you spell with both letters in uppercase, one is mixed case ...... try to be **consistent** - either spell `ID` always - or use `Id` always - but **do NOT MIX** ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why was an index created for TrackId but not for ProductId?

This is actually very clever, and correct behavior by EF.  The Primary Key on TblProductItem is (ProductId,TrackId).  So you *already* have an index supporting that Foreign Key (Since the FK columns are the leading columns in that index).  Only the trailing PK column (TrackId) needs a seperate index to support the Foreign Key.

Comment: I do not clearly understand why composite PK is working like this. I mean why one column of such PK is "leading" and others are "trailing". Could you please attach some links that explain how it works in a database and what's the advantages? I appreciate your answer anyway.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795031/how-do-composite-indexes-work